# Fade out entire page using a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to use a Chrome extension to fade an entire page in and out.

I started with the example where it turns the background red, and I tried to add the fadeOut function to the body, but that portion doesn't work - only the turning red part works.

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"; document.body.fadeOut();'
  });
});
```

Any ideas? Also, I am trying to figure out the difference between document.body and $('body').  I am new to javascript, and it seems like when I search for solutions (ie "how to fade entire page in javascript") they use $('body'), while the chrome extension code uses document.body.  I'm not sure if they are compatible. Thanks!

Comment: The `$` you've seen has likely been the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: Indeed and the fadeOut doesn't work precisely because it is a jQuery method. Try calling it from the Chrome console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're only using Chrome you can do this without needing jQuery.

Change the code line to run:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"; 
document.body.style.transition = "opacity 1s ease-in-out";
document.body.style.opacity = 0;
```

You can try this from the console window in dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `$(document.body).fadeOut();`. By the way, you must include jQuery in your [Content Script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) before you can run fadeOut().